# How can cells in one table be assigned values from another table in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables: **Content** and **Templates**.

• The schema of the **Content** table is as follows:

id | name | parent

where *parent* is the id of some of the rows in the Templates table.

The scheme of **Templates** table is as follows:

id | name | text

How can I make it so that, depending on the parent value in the Content table, the value "name" is assigned a name from the Templates table?

For example:

If the rows in the Templates table look like this:

```
| 7 | pencils | some text      |
| 8 | pens    | some other text|
```

, then in the row in the Content table, the row with parent 7 should get the name "pencils", and the row with parent 8 should get the name "pens"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do exactly what you ask you can use an UPDATE query with a JOIN:

```
update content join template on content.parent = template.id set content.name = template.name;
```

This will match the rows from `content` to the rows in `template` where `parent` matches `id`, and set the column in `content`.

However, you'd need to run this query every time new content is added since it won't automatically copy the data for you.

A better solution is to `SELECT` from the `JOINED` table so that your `SELECT` queries always retrieve the data from the `template` table.

For example:

```
select content.id, template.name, template.text from content join template on content.parent = template.id ;
```

See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5MsxuiPZNAsHHEF5m5THds/1